# Navbar with elements positioned both left and right without float

Tags: html, css, navbar

I'm trying to create a navbar which contains several links aligned to the left side, and a search form consisting of an image button and a text field aligned to the right. So far, the only solutions I have seen involve using a float, which I want to steer well clear of, since it completely breaks my page when I zoom or adjust the browser width.

Currently, my code is as follows:

```
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="bar">
        <span style="border-right:1px solid #555;padding-top:11px;padding-bottom:11px;"></span><!--
        --><a class="nav" href=...</a><!--
        --><a class="nav" href=...</a><!--
        --><a class="nav" href=...</a><!--
        --><span style="border-left:1px solid #000;padding-top:11px;padding-bottom:11px;"></span><!--
        --><div class="search">
            <form style="width:100%;text-align:left;">
                <input type="image" src="Images/search.png" alt="Search"/>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search" style="width:50%;border:none;"/>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .navbar{background:#000 url('../Images/navBG.png') repeat-x;font-weight:bold;border-top:1px solid #BBB;border-bottom:1px solid #BBB;}
    .bar{margin:0 auto;max-width:1280px;min-width:800px;width:84%;padding:10px;}
    .bar div{display:inline-block;}
    .bar a{padding:11px;}
    .nav{border-left:1px solid #000;border-right:1px solid #555;}
    .search{text-align:right;background:#FFF;overflow:hidden;border-radius:5px;}
```

This is currently set up so that the search bar is positioned the same as the rest of the links. That is, to the left. I'm not sure how I can put it to the right.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `display:table` attribute if you want IE8+ support and no `float` usage!! :)

[**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/g4JDk/1/)

```
body, html {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.navbar {
    background:#000 url('../Images/navBG.png') repeat-x;
    font-weight:bold;
    border-top:1px solid #BBB;
    border-bottom:1px solid #BBB;
    display:table;   /*added*/
    width:100%;   /*added*/
}
.bar {
    display:table-cell;/*added*/
    width:50%;   /*added*/
}
.bar a {
    padding:11px;
}
.nav {
    border-left:1px solid #000;
    border-right:1px solid #555;
}
.search {
    text-align:right;
    background:#FFF;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-radius:5px;
    display:table-cell;    /*added*/
    width:50%;    /*added*/
}
```

Comment: Hmm, It didn't work as expected on my page, but I just realised now that I forgot to add the "class=nav" attribute to the <a> tags in the navbar. Still, I think there must be more to it than that, since the positioning of the links was changed as well. Currently, the CSS makes it so that there is a certain gap on the left and right side of the page, and the gap reduces proportionally with smaller browser widths to 0 when it hits the min-width. Adding your changes, it immediately loses the gap on the left side.

Comment: @user3176616: you could do that tweaking. but yes, `table` and `table-cell` is the way to go. see this fiddle: ***http://jsfiddle.net/2YkL2/*** : i reduced the max and min widths a little so that you can see it easily in the fiddle.